# Detecting App Installation

Tags: android

Edit: Managed to solve it. Created a new project, cleared app data before uninstalling it, re-installed it, and it magically worked. Thanks for the help.

I'm trying to detect when an app is installed, but I'm not quite sure where I am going wrong. I've checked several questions on here, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I'm pretty new to android, so I may have missed something obvious. Here is the test case of what I have.

I installed it to my phone, and the process and service is shown as running in the settings. Then, I download an app from the play store, check the logcat, and there is nothing from the app.

Any help on where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Edit:

After playing with it some more, I have some new example test code. When a new package is installed, the onReceive method doesn't fire. However, as I was testing things out, I added a constructor to the BroadcastReceiver class, and the constructor fires everytime a package is installed. So, it seems to be receiving the intent, but the log inside the onReceive never seems to print out. Any ideas?

```
public class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public InstallReceiver()
    {
        //This log will display in the logcat
        Log.d("InstallReceiver", "InstallReceiver constructor called.");
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //This log never displays if the constructor is in or commented out
        Log.d("InstallReceiver", "Install detected.");
    }

}
```

---

```
<receiver android:name=".InstallReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"  />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: please what was your solution to this error?.

Comment: This code was for an assignment when I was doing my undergraduate. I really don't remember anything about the code. However, the project code is on [my github](https://github.com/DL-Thompson/SpyNot) if you would like to look through it. It did work at the time, but I'm not sure what changes may have been made to Android.

Answer (score 1):

Include this also in

```
<receiver android:name=".InstallReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Everything else that you've done seems correct.

The only other possibility is as prijupaul says, for security reasons this broadcast may not be working anymore.

Comment: I tried this too, and I still can't get it to work. I think it is still working in the system though. I have antivirus programs on my phone that trigger when a new app is downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

from the developer.android.com ref. - "Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast." - so you can't detect your own package installation. it should detect other package installations.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) says: "Broadcast Action: A new application package has been installed on the device. The data contains the name of the package. **Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.**"

Comment: I took that to mean that a newly installed package does not receive the broadcast of installation from itself when it is being installed. I was trying to detect installs of other packages after my package had been installed. Their wording there does seem a little unclear in my opinion, but I did get it working, so that is my best guess to the meaning.

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK, This is not possible in Android for privacy reasons. There is no broadcast that says, an app has been installed.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding the documentation, this is it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED